Which is the best working combination of versions for eslint, eslint-config-next, next, react and react-dom?
which is the best working combination of versions for Eslint, Eslint-config-next, Next, React and React-dom?
Present combination of Eslint (9.17.0), Eslint-config-next (15.1.3), Next (15.1.3), React (18.3.1) and React-dom (18.3.1) gives me headaches with simple 'hello world' homepage.
I'm a newbie with these technologies.
They give me an error with 'npm run build' exited with code 1.
I tried suggestions from other threads like to delete node-modules and package-lock.json file and the 'npm install' again but... no luck for me.
So I guess it could also be underlying problems with different versions of above mentioned tech.
Thanks very much in advance.
